# Uploading an image in dojo

Tags: ajax, dojo

How to upload an image in Dojo with its ajax call? The url of the image must get stored to the database.Is there anyway to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dojo's xhr methods don't support binary data. You might want to use [dojox.form.Uploader](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojox/form/Uploader.html)

Answer (score 1):

you could try an aproach using a hidden iframe

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" target="magicFrame" action="uploader.php">
    <input type="file" name="image" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<iframe name="magicFrame" id="magicFrame" style="display: none" ></iframe>
```

this will achieve the same result as uploading the image by AJAX (is not currently posible)